# Function 'PRECENTILE_CONT' error #Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

When I run the below query:

```
select PRECENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY X) AS MEDIAN_X
from table;
```

I get the following error:

> Function 'PRECENTILE_CONT' is not an analytic aggregate but is called
>   with a window spec

Please let me know if you have a solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

The function should be `PERCENTILE_CONT`. A typo i guess.

Comment: I thought the keyword was PRECENTILE_CONT and didn't bother to think it as a typo. Also, the weird error message didn't help.But it turns out, it is a typo! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Re-arrange the syntax of query as below :

```
select PERCENTILE_CONT ( 0.5 ) 
WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY x )
OVER ( [ <partition_by_clause> ] ) as MEDIAN_X from table
```

Comment: Thanks for this but just so you know I got the following error when I modified to this.

'PERCENTILE_CONT' is not a window function and cannot be used with the over() clause